# Determining statistical relationships between rasters using R vs ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-statistics

I am trying to analyze how sets of rasters relate to each other using some statistical techniques. As, I don't have much experience using the spatial statistics tools in *ArcGIS* I was exporting my rasters as *Ascii* files, and analyzing them using *R* (specifically the `maptools` package, and `readAsciiGrid()` ). This has been functioning ok (but as the datasets have 90,000 points it is slow to run the analysis), but I don't know if I am recreating in *R*, existing functionality in *ArcGIS*.

For example, I want to perform regressions between each of these rasters using a few different transformations (logarithmic, exponential, etc). Can this be done within *ArcGIS*? A second broader question is if there are standard statistical methods for examining this type of data?

Each raster pair has matching data/no-data values and all parameters are identical, aside from the gridcell value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would stick to R. If speed is really a problem ( I doubt so 90.000 is not such a big number) you could try finding relationships between a subset of your data.
Actually the first thing I would do is make a plot to look for obvious relationships.

Even if arcgis contains tools to compare rasters, R will always give you a lot more statistical tools.

Eg:

```
library(rgdal)
map1<-readGDAL('file.asc')
map2<-readGDAL('file2.asc')
samplenr<-sample(length(map1$band1), 1000)
smallset<-data.frame(map1=map1$band1[samplenr],map2=map2$band1[samplenr])
plot(smallset)
lm(map2~map1, smallset)
...
```

I should actually add that often it is more correct to work with a subset of your data then with your full dataset. In many cases grid cells are not independent from the surrounding data cells, which will result in overly optimistic p values for eg regression fits (you will find more info if you search on declustering).

Comment: +1.  Neither ArcGIS nor, for that matter, *any* GIS will ever natively provide capabilities like R or other full-featured statistical packages.  It would be foolish for them to try.  What we can hope for--and ArcGIS appears to be in the early stages--is for the GIS platform to provide efficient integration with other applications for statistical analysis and visualization.

Comment: It's true - speed is not really an issue. It takes about 10s to load two rasters and a 10-15 seconds per operation thus far. If I keep things in perspective, I've waited just as long in ArcGIS for things to happen! I plan to use sampling more, though which will remove any slight delay.

Answer (score 5):

Look into the R [raster package](http://raster.r-forge.r-project.org/), it was designed with this specific kind of problem in mind. It tries to keep as little of the raster in memory, and performs a number of basic spatial operations -- via GDAL it can handle native ESRI Grid files, among many other formats. The vignette [provides some nice examples](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf) of its use.

Answer (score 1):

I just read about an ArcGIS 10 [package](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F855D6D1-1422-2418-A0B2-643E624A8925) that is an R plugin. I have not had the chance to explore it fully, but it might be possible to modify this to do what I describe above.